# Bind dropdown list to editItemTemplate & footerTemplate in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I have a grid where I try to bind dropdown list to an FooterTemplate and EdiItemTemplate.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role" SortExpression="Role">
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px"   HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRole" runat="server">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFRRole" runat="server">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblRole" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Role_Cd]") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

I am using this code and no luck. I am not able to bind the values to the drop down. Can anyone correct me if I am wrong?

```
protected void UPGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddlRole = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlRole");
            DropDownList ddlFRRole = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlFRRole");
            ddlRole.DataSource = UPRepository.GetRoles();                
            ddlRole.DataTextField = "Role_Cd";
            ddlRole.DataValueField = "Role_Cd";
            ddlRole.DataBind();
            ddlFRRole.DataSource = UPRepository.GetRoles();                
            ddlFRRole.DataTextField = "Role_Cd";
            ddlFRRole.DataValueField = "Role_Cd";
            ddlFRRole.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should first check and compare the `RowIndex` with the GridView's `EditIndex` which is to be edited and place the whole code binding the dropdown inside.

***Also, for finding the dropdownlist in footer you need to use condition:***

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
```

***And, for finding dropdownlist in a row use***

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
```

Bind your Dropdown inside `RowDataBound` event of `GridView`.
Now your code should be::

```
protected void MyGridView_RowDataBound( object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(MyGridView.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex ) //GET THE ROW TO BE EDITED
         {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
              {
               DropDownList ddlRole = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlRole");
                // Rest of Code
              }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
         {
           DropDownList ddlFRRole = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlFRRole");
           // Rest of code
         }
    }
```

Another option is to use the below condition to check for the Row being Edited ::

```
if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
```

OR equivalently:: `if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)`

Comment: Try this condition: " if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0) " as this also worked for me. Are you binding the Dropdown in RowDataBound event of GridView ?? Check the updated answer